# SpecRunner : Test Method getting called twice

Tags: specflow, specrun

I am using Spec Runner to run my test cases, the scenrios are getting called twice.

What might be the issue?

Please find the below scenario and test results attached

[Scenario](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qfy17.png)[TestResults](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OpoHa.png)

Answer (score 2):

Are they failing scenarios? In the standard configuration SpecFlow+Runner retries failing tests.

To disable the retry of a scenario, you have to set the retryCount parameter in the execution element to 0. See http://www.specflow.org/plus/documentation/SpecFlowPlus-Runner-Profiles/#Execution

Full disclosure: I am one of the developers of the SpecFlow+Runner.

Comment: Hi Andreas, Not failing,they get succeeded and again they re- run. let me try your suggestion.